# DecimalSeparator issue with String.Format()

Tags: java, locale, string-formatting, decimalformat

Please find my code below:

```
double value = (double)-16325.62015;
System.out.println(String.format("%s", value));//-16325.62015
System.out.println(String.format(new Locale("de", "DE"), "%s", value));//-16325.62015
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(new Locale("de", "DE"));
System.out.println(dfs.getDecimalSeparator());//,
```

In the above code, Im getting the wrong decimal separator for German locale.

I have tried the below code also but it produces -16325,6

```
double value = (double)-16325.62015;
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(new Locale("de", "DE"));
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#", dfs ); 
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

is there any alternative way to print the output as  -16325,62015

Note: I want to print double value with n number of decimal places for any specific locale

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't formatting number: you are formatting string. Look carefully what different parameters such as `%s` mean.

Comment: In second code snippet, it produces exactly what it told `DecimalFormat` to produce: a floating point with single digit precision. I again advise you to look into what various decimal format mean and how to configure one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `%f` not `%s`. When `%s` is used, Java converts your value to String using `String.valueOf` which uses the default locale.

```
double value = (double)-16325.62015;
System.out.println(String.format("%f", value));
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%f", value));
```